# Field calculator & features filtered by Datetimes

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, temporal-controller

I'm using the Temporal Controller, and i'm trying to point out a label from layer A, on layer B. The layer B is empty (`NULL`), but has a field that brings the label of certain features of layer A. I think it can be done using the `@map_start_time` of the Temporal Controller. I've tried aggregate, and other functions as follows (for layer B label):

```
label expression= aggregate('Layer A','count',fid)
```

I get the total number of features on layer A. I'm typing the wrong formula.

The line of code should be able to tell how many features have appeared either since t=0, or the last time interval...

I'm struggling to make a variation of the label 'A' over time. Any ideas on how to write down this using the field calculator?